# Accessing a variable in the current instance of a form

Tags: c#, wpf, instance

For accessing a variable in another form or class, it's the right way to create a new instance of that class/form and basically access the variable using properties.(get/set)

However, what if I already have an instance of that form running in the background? Is it possible to access that form's variables without creating a new instance?

What I've done so far is, I tried to store `Application.Current.Windows[i]` in an object and to access the variable using it. Well, it didn't work despite casting.

i.e

The variable I want to access is in a form called MainWindow, so what I've tried is;

```
    Private MainWindow mW;
    mW = (MainWindow)Application.Current.Windows[1]; //since it's the second window
    mW.Variable = dummy;
```

What are your suggestions on this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: > "Well, it didn't work". Could you post any exceptions here?

Comment: Sure, the exception is a classic one, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

It suggests me to use the keyword new to create a new instance.

Comment: stack trace and line number will be helpful. Probability of NRE in `(MainWindow)Application.Current.Windows[1]` is towards a zero. Also, (if exception occurs in `mW.Variable = dummy;`):  `mW.Variable` is a field or a property? If it is a property, please, post setter code.